# AVG acusa infecção em Aplicação Windows Service se comando de adição ao Firewall do Windows estiver presente

Tags: delphi, delphi-6, antivirus, firewall

Tenho uma aplicação que é um ***Windows Service*** (Serviço do Windows) e por conta de facilidades estou buscando adicionar um método para adicioná-lo ao ***Firewall*** do ***Windows*** automaticamente.

Assim:

```delphi
procedure AddInFirewall(cApplicationName, cEntryName: string);
var
  cAppName: string;
begin
  if Trim(cApplicationName) = '' then
    cAppName := Application.ExeName
  else
    cAppName := cApplicationName;

  if Trim(cEntryName) = '' then
    begin
      cEntryName := ExtractFileName(cAppName);
    end;

  WinExec(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('netsh firewall delete allowedprogram ' + cAppName)), SW_HIDE);
  WinExec(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="'+cEntryName+'" program="'+cAppName+'"')), SW_HIDE);

  WinExec(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('netsh firewall add allowedprogram '+cAppName+' "'+cEntryName+'" ENABLE')), SW_HIDE);
  WinExec(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="'+cEntryName+'" dir=in action=allow program="'+cAppName+'" enable=yes')), SW_HIDE);
end;

procedure TServerModule.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddInFirewall(Application.ExeName, 'MeuServico');
  FClients := TList.Create;
  StartService;
end;
```

Todavia, o bendito do AVG antivírus está reclamando que ele está infectado com o:

> Win32/DH{IFVEIS4}

Basta eu comentar as linhas com `WinExec` e compilar novamente que ele não reclama mais a infecção.

**Como posso resolver tal problema?**

Comment: Achei interessante ninguem ter respondido falando deste ponto importante: você fez a assinatura digital do seu executável? Esse é um dos passos para que o comportamento de uma série de partes do sistema "olhe sua aplicação com outros olhos". Isso inclui parte dos anti-virus.

Comment: Sim. Você providencia um certificado digital, e assina o executável com este certificado. Assim resolve uma série de problemas, inclusive as mensagens de "origem desconhecida" e uma série de alertas do Windows. Fazer executável avulso é uma coisa, quando vc quer coisas pra ambiente corporativo, como um service, não dá pra ficar na solução caseira: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361.aspx http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing

Comment: PS: Isso não é um substituto a chamar a API do firewall da maneira correta, mas sim um complemento importante pra esse tipo de aplicação.

Comment: Você falou do seu programa ser tratado como virus, a assinatura digital é parte das soluções ué...

Comment: Bom achado :) eu nao lembro de ter visto essa questão antes. (e é xará seu, ou conta velha? acabo de ver que o nome antigo do user é @Tiago)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>*A pergunta em si já foi respondida na outra resposta então, tentarei apenas complementá-la.*</sub>

Esse trecho de código `WinExec(....)` é bastante conhecido(*manjado/batido*) pelos antivírus pelo fato de estar fazendo isso em segundo plano, o antivírus está certo em considerar sua aplicação como um *malware*.

Tente abordar isso de alguma outra forma, tal como utilizar as *APIs* do *Windows Firewall*, mais precisamente utilizando as interfaces [`INetFwPolicy2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) e [`FWRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Veja o seguinte exemplo que tentará adicionar uma regra a uma aplicação(**Nota**: *é necessário privilégios para executar a aplicação*):

```pascal
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj;

// Este código adiciona uma regra de aplicativo usando as APIs do Windows Firewall.
Procedure AddApplicationRule;
Const
 NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW = 1;
 NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP = 6;
var
 CurrentProfiles : OleVariant;
 fwPolicy2       : OleVariant;
 RulesObject     : OleVariant;
 NewRule         : OleVariant;
begin
  // Cria o objeto que permite acessar a política de Firewall
  fwPolicy2   := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
  RulesObject := fwPolicy2.Rules;
  CurrentProfiles := fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;

  // Cria o objeto que proporcionará acessar as propriedades de uma regra.
  NewRule := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FWRule');

  NewRule.Name := 'Foo Bar';  // Nome da Aplicação
  NewRule.Description := 'My Powerful Service Example'; // Descrição da Aplicação
  NewRule.Applicationname := ParamStr(0); // Caminho da Aplicaçao
  NewRule.Protocol := NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
  NewRule.LocalPorts := 4000; // Porta
  NewRule.Enabled := True;
  NewRule.Grouping := ''; // Grupo
  NewRule.Profiles := CurrentProfiles;
  NewRule.Action := NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;

  // Adiciona a nova regra
  RulesObject.Add(NewRule);
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      AddApplicationRule;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Ao abrir o painel de configurações avançadas do Firewall (Digite `firewall.cpl` no *Executar do Windows* - no lado esquerdo clique em **Configurações Avançadas**) a aplicação estará presente lá.

[image: k]

Espero não ter fugido do foco da pergunta. Para obter mais informações sobre como manipular o *Firewall* através das *APIs* veja [`esse tópico`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) no *MSDN* e [`aqui`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/using-the-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-scripting-api-and-delphi/) precisamente em *Delphi*.

### Atualização

A partir da resposta do @Renan, consegui reproduzir o que ele mencionou, **não tenho certeza se o antivírus bloqueará ou não**, segue o procedimento `AddInFirewall()` modificado(*testado no Windows 7*):

```pascal
procedure AddInFirewall(cApplicationName, cEntryName: string);
Var
  TShell: TShellExecuteInfo;
  cAppName: string;
begin
  if Trim(cApplicationName) = '' then
    cAppName := Application.ExeName
  else
    cAppName := cApplicationName;

  if Trim(cEntryName) = '' then
    cEntryName := ExtractFileName(cAppName);

  FillChar(TShell, sizeof(TShell), 0);
  TShell.cbSize := SizeOf(TShell);
  TShell.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  TShell.Wnd := Application.Handle;
  TShell.lpVerb := Nil;
  TShell.nShow := SW_NORMAL; // Utilize SW_HIDE para esconder a janela
  TShell.lpFile := 'cmd.exe';
  TShell.lpParameters := PWideChar('/k netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="' + cEntryName + '" dir=in action=allow program="' + cApplicationName + '" enable=yes');
  TShell.lpVerb := 'runas';

  ShellExecuteEx(@TShell);
  WaitForSingleObject(TShell.hProcess, INFINITE);
  CloseHandle(TShell.hProcess);

  ShowMessage('Procedimento concluido!');
end;
```

Chame o procedimento do mesmo modo que você estava fazendo, assim:

```
AddInFirewall(Application.ExeName, 'MeuServico');
```

Ao chamar a função, criaremos o processo `cmd.exe` e passaremos como parâmetro o comando responsável por adicionar a aplicação ao Firewall, um *popup* do **UAC** aparecerá pedindo confirmação para executar `cmd.exe` com *direitos elevados*.

Através de `WaitForSingleObject` só poderemos continuar a utilizar a aplicação depois que `cmd.exe` ter sido finalizado.

Se tudo ocorrer bem, veremos o *Prompt de Comando* mostrar algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E por fim, no painel de configurações avançadas do Firewall:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom @DBX8!!

Comment: +1, e esta deveria ser a resposta marcada como correta.

Answer (score 7):

Se uma aplicação requer uma configuração especial de firewall, a configuração deve ser feita por um administrador. No seu caso, o antivírus está correto em assumir que seu programa é um malware.

Pense nisso. Se qualquer aplicação pudesse modificar as regras do Firewall com uma chamada específica a alguma API, sem alertar nenhum sistema de proteção... O que me impediria de distribuir alguma aplicação, um joguinho freemium talvez, que abrisse todas as portas do seu firewall e habilitasse todos os protocolos?

No seu caso, quanto a adicionar uma aplicação, o Windows pode cuidar disso automaticamente - o UAC sobe e pede confirmação ao usuário para adicionar a aplicação na lista de permissões. Mas remover uma regra do Firewall, programaticamente? Não. Apenas e nada mais do que não.

Comment: @Crood quando a aplicação for rodar pela primeira vez, o usuário que estiver logado deve ver aquele diálogo que escurece o resto da tela e diz qualquer coisa como "tem certeza de que deseja permitir que esse programa acesse recursos de rede", e que permite escolher se vai liberar as portas só em redes privadas ou em redes públicas também. Se não aparecer, bem, aí eu realmente não sei como proceder. Espero que alguém mais experiente possa ajudar aqui, mas sugiro perguntar também no SOen. Não sei se a pergunta se encaixa no [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com) também.